# REST for ASP.NET MVC included in MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-2

Are the REST for ASP.NET MVC bits automatically included with MVC 2, or do you need to download/install/use the REST for ASP.NET MVC bits separately?

Specifically, I'm referring to the REST for ASP.NET MVC download here: http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24471#DownloadId=79561

I want to use REST for ASP.NET MVC for the automatic json/xml serialization based on the incoming request's accepted content type. I'm not really finding any info about MVC2's ability to do this out of the "box".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not included, you need to reference the `System.Web.Mvc.Resources` assembly in your project. There's a word document included in the download giving some examples.